# Symfony 5.4 LDAP and User-Entity Password mixed

Tags: symfony, ldap

Is ist possible to configure user authentification for Symfony 5.4 using either User/Password stored in the User entity oder LDAP depending on a boolean field or the password being null in the User entity?

I need to create some users that have to log on but are not contained in the customers LDAP structure. LDAP is more a comfort thing (single credentials for all apps) here than a security one (no one may logon if not defined in LDAP).

Perhaps I can get around programming the security things from the scatch and just combine two different providers.

Comment: Same problem here. When I try to login with local user Symfony's `CheckLdapCredentialsListener` throws an exception which makes the authentication fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I solved it and it was quite easy by using the "normal" password authenticator and modifying a bit of code. The strategy is:

1. Check if its an LDAP user. If not, use password authentication
2. Search the user in the LDAP directory
3. Bail out if not found
4. Bail out if not unique
5. Check credentials

The steps I took:

1. I added a boolean field to the entity USER called ldap_flag
2. I added variables to .env to specify the LDAP parameters
3. I modified Security/LoginFormAuthenticator:checkCredentials like this:

   ```
   if ($user->getLDAPFlag()) {

       if ($conn = ldap_connect($_ENV['LDAP_HOST'])) {
           ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, $_ENV['LDAP_PROTOCOL_VERSION']);
           ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
           if ($_ENV['LDAP_CERT_CHECK'] == 0)
               ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_NEVER);
           $dn = $_ENV['LDAP_BIND_DN'];
           $pw = $_ENV['LDAP_BIND_PW'];
           if (ldap_bind($conn, $dn, $pw)) {
               // Search user
               $res = ldap_search($conn, $_ENV['LDAP_SEARCH_DN'], "(&(uid=" . $user->getUserName() . ")(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))", array('dn'));
               $entries = ldap_get_entries($conn, $res);
               if ($entries["count"] == 1)
                   return ldap_bind($conn, $entries[0]['dn'], $credentials['password']);
               else if ($entries["count"] > 0)
                   throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Benutzer im LDAP nicht eindeutig!');
               else
                   throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Benutzer auf dem LDAP Server nicht gefunden!');
           } else
               // cannot bind
               throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Kann nicht an LDAP-Server binden!');
           ldap_unind($conn);
       } else {
           // no LDAP Connection
           throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Keine Verbindung zum LDAP-Server');
       }
   } else
       // internal password-check
       return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
   ```

   }

The error messages are in German but it should be easy to adapt them to an other language as they explain within their context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain how you modified `Security/LoginFormAuthenticator:checkCredentials`? Did you used overriding via `services.yaml`?

Comment: The file was already staying there (src/Security/LoginFormAuthenticator.php and I just modified the existing function checkCredentials within that file. No further modification was neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

I have found another solution, which makes use of Symfony's services. But it is not a one liner. One has to define several configurations, override some services and create two custom classes.

But this advices should be relatively complete.

```yaml
# config/packages/security.yaml

security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    providers:
        all_users:
            chain:
                providers: [ldap_users, local_users]
        local_users:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
        ldap_users:
            # in services.yml Symfony's provider is overwritten with
            # App\Security\LdapUserProvider
            ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap # see services.yml
                base_dn: '%env(LDAP_BASE_DN)%'
                search_dn: '%env(LDAP_SEARCH_DN)%'
                search_password: '%env(LDAP_SEARCH_PASSWORD)%'
                default_roles: ROLE_USER
                uid_key: '%env(LDAP_UID_KEY)%'
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            lazy: true
            provider: all_users
            form_login_ldap:
                check_path: app_login
                login_path: app_login
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap # see services.yml
                dn_string: '%env(LDAP_BASE_DN)%'
                search_dn: '%env(LDAP_SEARCH_DN)%'
                search_password: '%env(LDAP_SEARCH_PASSWORD)%'
                query_string: 'sAMAccountName={username}'
```

```yaml
# config/services.yaml
services:
    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
        arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']
        tags:
            - ldap

    Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
        arguments:
            - host: '%env(LDAP_HOST)%'
              port: 389
              encryption: none
              options: { protocol_version: 3, referrals: false, network_timeout: 5 }

    # overwrite symfony's LdapUserProvider so that a User entity is used
    # instead of the default user class of Symfony.
    security.user.provider.ldap:
        class: App\Security\LdapUserProvider
        arguments: [~, ~, ~, ~, ~, ~, ~, ~, ~]

    App\Security\AppCredentialsCheckListener:
        decorates: 'security.listener.form_login_ldap.main'
        arguments:
            $checkLdapCredentialsListener: '@.inner'
            $checkCredentialsListener: '@security.listener.check_authenticator_credentials'
```

```php
// src/Security/LdapUserProvider.php
namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Ldap\Entry;
use Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Ldap\Security\LdapUserProvider as BaseLdapUserProvider;

/**
 * This service is responsible for adding a user entity to the local database.
 */
class LdapUserProvider extends BaseLdapUserProvider
{
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;

    private UserRepository $userRepo;

    public function __construct(
        LdapInterface $ldap,
        string $baseDn,
        string $searchDn,
        string $searchPassword,
        array $defaultRoles,
        string $uidKey,
        string $filter,
        ?string $passwordAttribute,
        ?array $extraFields,
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        UserRepository $userRepo
    ) {
        parent::__construct($ldap, $baseDn, $searchDn, $searchPassword, $defaultRoles, $uidKey, $filter, $passwordAttribute, $extraFields);

        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->userRepo = $userRepo;
    }

    protected function loadUser(string $username, Entry $entry)
    {
        $ldapUser = parent::loadUser($username, $entry);

        $user = $this->userRepo->findOneBy(['username' => $ldapUser->getUsername()]);
        $flush = false;

        if (!$user) {
            $user = new User();
            $user->setUsername($ldapUser->getUsername());
            
            $this->entityManager->persist($user);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
        }

        return $user;
    }
}
```

```php
// src/Security/AppCredentialsCheckListener.php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Ldap\Security\CheckLdapCredentialsListener;
use Symfony\Component\Ldap\Security\LdapBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\CheckPassportEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EventListener\CheckCredentialsListener;

/**
 * This event listener is responsible for checking the password.
 * First the LDAP password is checked and as a fallback the local
 * password is checked
 */
class AppCredentialsCheckListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private CheckLdapCredentialsListener $checkLdapCredentialsListener;

    private CheckCredentialsListener $checkCredentialsListener;

    public function __construct(
        CheckLdapCredentialsListener $checkLdapCredentialsListener,
        CheckCredentialsListener $checkCredentialsListener
    ) {
        $this->checkLdapCredentialsListener = $checkLdapCredentialsListener;
        $this->checkCredentialsListener = $checkCredentialsListener;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        // priority must be higher than the priority of the Symfony listeners
        return [CheckPassportEvent::class => ['onCheckPassport', 999]];
    }

    public function onCheckPassport(CheckPassportEvent $event)
    {
        try {
            // Check ldap password
            $this->checkLdapCredentialsListener->onCheckPassport($event);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException $e) {
            // Fallback to local entity password
            $this->checkCredentialsListener->checkPassport($event);

            // We have to mark the ldap badge as resolved. Otherwise an exception will be thrown.
            /** @var LdapBadge $ldapBadge */
            $ldapBadge = $event->getPassport()->getBadge(LdapBadge::class);
            $ldapBadge->markResolved();
        }
    }
}
```

I have added some comments to the config and the code, which should make clear how it is achieved. I hope it helps anyone.